# Finding an unknown angle (some constructions needed).

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Any ideas how I could find the size of $\angle CBD$ in the diagram given that AC=AD, $\angle CAB=6$, $\angle CBA=48$ and $\angle DAC=12$.

I think there should be a way to do it with basic geometry provided the right auxiliary lines are constructed.

[image]

The two things which led me to some progress where 1. Draw a perpendicular bisector from A to DC and an altitude from AB to C which gave me 3 congruent triangles, unfortunately I couldn't work and of the sides from CDB into it.

The second was to extend DC to make it the same length as AD and AC, this created another isosceles triangle with base angles of 48 degrees the base of this side made a cyclic quadrilateral with points A, B & C ... but unfortunately I still couldn't use the new information to solve for x (I was mainly looking to make congruent triangles)

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg 

The two things which led me to some progress where 1. Draw a perpendicular bisector from A to DC and an altitude from AB to C which gave me 3 congruent triangles, unfortunately I couldn't work and of the sides from CDB into it.

The second was to extend DC to make it the same length as AD and AC, this created another isosceles triangle with base angles of 48 degrees the base of this side made a cyclic quadrilateral with points A, B & C ... but unfortunately I still couldn't use the new information to solve for x (I was mainly looking to make congruent triangles).

Comment: I used the Cheva's theorem. Do you want to see it? Or the solution must be without trigonometry?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I was aiming to do it with constructions and Euclidean/Circle Geometry theorems but I'd still definitely like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $\measuredangle ADC=84^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle CDB=30^{\circ}-x.$

Thus, by Cheva we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin(30^{\circ}-x)\sin48^{\circ}\sin12^{\circ}}{\sin{x}\sin6^{\circ}\sin84^{\circ}}=1$$ or

$$\frac{2\sin(30^{\circ}-x)\sin48^{\circ}}{\sin{x}}=1,$$ which gives $$x=18^{\circ}.$$

Indeed, since the exspression $\frac{\sin(30^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}}$ decreases on $(0^{\circ},30^{\circ})$,

there is an unique value of $x$ such that $$\frac{2\sin(30^{\circ}-x)\sin48^{\circ}}{\sin{x}}=1.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{2\sin(30^{\circ}-18^{\circ})\sin48^{\circ}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=1,$$ which is true because
$$\frac{2\sin(30^{\circ}-18^{\circ})\sin48^{\circ}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=\frac{2\sin12^{\circ}\sin48^{\circ}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=\frac{\sin18^{\circ}-\sin18^{\circ}+\cos36^{\circ}-\cos60^{\circ}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin18^{\circ}+\frac{2\sin36^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}-2\sin36^{\circ}\sin18^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}-\cos60^{\circ}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin18^{\circ}+\frac{\sin72^{\circ}-\cos18^{\circ}+\cos54^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}-\frac{1}{2}}{\sin{18^{\circ}}}=1.$$

Comment: Didn't think of that at all, but this technique looks like it will open up a lot of questions. This may be a sill question but how did you go from the last line to the second last line? I am struggling to make x the subject.

Comment: @2d1nn3rz I added something. See now.